# What is the purpose of this function in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I am reading an assembly code, and I do not have the source code available. There is one function called `next_text` in the assembly that I am struggling to understand. Can anyone help me on this?

```
      next_text()

       push   %rbp
       push   %rbx
       sub    $0x108,%rsp
       mov    %rdi,%rbp
       mov    %esi,%ebx
       jmp    <next_text+45>
   16  mov    %rbp,%rdx
       mov    $0x100,%esi
       mov    %rsp,%rdi
       callq  <fgets@plt>
       test   %rax,%rax
       jne    <next_text+42>
       callq  <func>
   42  sub    $0x1,%ebx
   45  test   %ebx,%ebx
       jg     <next_text+16>
       add    $0x108,%rsp
       pop    %rbx
       pop    %rbp
       retq
```

Here `%ebx` starts with certain large integer like `16000`. My understanding of what this function is doing is it takes an argument which is the file stream. It then reads the file line by line. The maximum length of the line is `100 hex` which is `256` characters. It then subtracts `ebx` by 1, and as long as the file is long enough, keeps on reading the file for `16000` lines, and at the end when `ebx` is `0`, it exits. Is my understanding correct? Also, is the command `sub    $0x108,%rsp` particularly important here, or is it just setting up the stack memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me like it is this:

```
void next_text(FILE *f, count) {
    char  buf[256];
    while (count-- > 0) {
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f)) {
            func();
        }
    }
}
```